# Why the jpg file I converted from a gif file isn't crisp and clear?

Tags: java, compression, jpeg, gif, javax.imageio

I use the following code to convert a gif file to a jpg file, it works but the result jpg file isn't the same quality as the original gif file, why ? Any way to improve the quality ?

```
try
{
  ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/abc.gif")),"jpg",new File("C:/abc.jpg"));
}
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

So, to ask this question from another angle, with the above approach, how to increase the output quality ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a [lossy image compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format which discards information that the human eyes can't notice very well. However, depending on the image quality settings when compressing the image, [compression artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact), such as blockiness and smudging can become visible -- this is the reason behind the image not appearing to be clear.

It may be possible that the [`ImageIO.write`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) method is saving the JPEG with a lower quality setting than necessary to keep the image looking good enough.

In order to set the quality setting higher, it will be necessary to use the [`ImageWriteParam`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html) to specify the image quality settings, then use the [`ImageWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html) to output the JPEG.

For example:

```
// Get a writer for JPEG.
ImageWriter iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
iw.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(outputFile));

// Set the compression quality to 0.9f.
ImageWriteParam iwParam = iw.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwParam.setCompressionQuality(0.9f);

// Write image
iw.write(null, new IIOImage(imageToWrite, null, null), iwParam);
```

Methods of interest:

- [`ImageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#setCompressionQuality(float))
- [`ImageWriter.write`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam))

That said, as the other answers mention, JPEG is unsuitable for compression of text and illustrations. If the goal is to preserve the image quality, but the file size can be bigger than with compression with JPEG, then using an [lossless image compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression) format such as [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) would preserve the image quality as it is, without any loss. However, in many cases, the file size of a PNG file will be larger than a JPEG. (But this is not always the case.)

The general rule of thumb is, for photographs and other realistic images, lossy compression formats such as JPEG will work well for the file size vs. quality trade off, while lossless compression formats such as PNG will work better for illustrations and line art, where there are large areas of similar color with little gradient effects.

Comment: Great, it works "almost" as I expected ! But I've noticed something interesting, I read in a png image and set the CompressionQuality to 1.0f, and I thought the output would look like the original image, but instead, light blue came out as dark blue, since it's a stock chart, I don't mind, I'm glad it works ! Thanks !

You can try it with the following chart : 
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=ibm&t=6m&q=b&l=off&z=m&p=&a=v,r14,ss,w14

Comment: @Frank: Even at compression quality of 1.0f, the compression will be lossy, so the quality of the output will not be identical to the original. I have observed changes to the color in the past, so that's probably one of the effects of the lossy compression.

Answer (score 11):

JPEG is specially bad for images with text inside. A good alternative is  .PNG.

Answer (score 5):

JPEG guarantees some loss in fidelity; that's how it achieves compression. You could choose a different block size that would minimize the artifacts, but there will be artifacts.

GIF is lossless and JPEG is lossy; abc.jpg will never be pixel equivalent to abc.gif.

Comment: There is a lossless part of the JPEG standard, yet nobody bothered to implement ist :)

Comment: Although GIF is lossless, it's worth noting that it is a lossless _indexed_ colour format, so some colour information is lost when saving from a Truecolor source. JPEG is a lossy truecolor format so the indexed image is upconverted to truecolor (without improvement in quality), then "averaged out" in a JPEG/DCT sense (with a corresponding decrease in quality).

Comment: There is also a lossy part of the GIF standard. Sigh, things aren't so simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, JPEG is suitable for images which are photographic in nature. If the image is one that contains large variations in colour, has naturalistic elements and resembles a live environment, then JPEG will provide good quality with no visible artifacts.

If the image is drawn, or contains large swathes of a single colour and is not photographic, then the image will be better compressed using PNG. This is a lossless format that can do 32 bit colour.

You should pretty much never use GIF format images these days - the format only supports 8 bit colour and provides relatively poor compression.