# Libpng, Palette png with alpha or not?

Tags: c++, png, libpng

How to know if palette png is with alpha or not?
I get information about the image `png_get_IHDR`

After that i look at `color_type - PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE`

But i can't find how to know if this png image has alpha channel or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PNG supports transparency in two (or three) quite different ways:

1. Truecolor or grayscale images with a separated **alpha channel** (RGBA or GA)
2. Transparency extra info  in the (optional) [**tRNS chunk**](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.tRNS) . Which has two different flavors:

   2a. For indexed images: the tRNS chunk specifies a transparency value ("alpha") for one, several or all the **palette indexes**.

   2b. For truecolor or grayscale images: the tRNS chunk specifies **a single color value** (RGB or Gray) that should be considered as fully transparent.

If you are interested in case *2a*, and if you are using libpng, you should look at  the function [png_get_tRNS()](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.get.trns.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

this may help:

```
if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA || color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GA)
    *alphaFlag = true;
else
{
    png_bytep trans_alpha = NULL;
    int num_trans = 0;
    png_color_16p trans_color = NULL;

    png_get_tRNS(png_ptr, info_ptr, &trans_alpha, &num_trans, &trans_color);
    if (trans_alpha != NULL)
        *alphaFlag = true;
    else
        *alphaFlag = false;
}
```