# Applying a grayscale on .png images

Tags: php, filter, png, alpha, grayscale

I'm trying convert a PNG to grayscale but i keep getting a black background instead of a transparent background. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

```
private function applyGrayscale($path,$name,$prefix,$infix='gray_'){
    list($filename,$extention) = explode('.',strtolower($name));

    switch($extention){
        case 'jpg'  :   $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$prefix.$name);break;
        case 'jpeg' :   $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$prefix.$name);break;
        case 'gif'  :   $image=imagecreatefromgif($path.$prefix.$name);break;
        case 'png'  :   $image=imagecreatefrompng($path.$prefix.$name);break;
        default     :   $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$prefix.$name);break;
    }

    imagealphablending($image, true);
    imagesavealpha($image,true);
    imageFilter($image,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

    switch($extention){
        case 'jpg'  :   imagejpeg($image,$path.$prefix.$infix.$name,100);break;
        case 'jpeg' :   imagejpeg($image,$path.$prefix.$infix.$name,100);break;
        case 'gif'  :   imagegif($image,$path.$prefix.$infix.$name);break;
        case 'png'  :   imagepng($image,$path.$prefix.$infix.$name,9);break;
        default     :   imagejpeg($image,$path.$prefix.$infix.$name,100);break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Imagick or Gmagick? More flexibility with those libraries

Comment: Your original image has an alpha channel? Bear in mind that there are several [PNG transparency flavors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973).