# What RGB values should I set for a transparent pixel in a .PNG file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, png

The transparency of a pixel in a .PNG file is determined by the value of the alpha channel:

- 0 - Transparent
- 255 - Opaque

It seems that once the pixel is set to be fully transparent, the RGB components of the pixel should be not important. Is that really true? Is there any convention or are there any guidelines on what RGB values should be set in fully transparent pixels?

In VS2012 when I try to draw with transparent color, nothing happens. It seems that VS applies  current color of the tool to the current state of the pixel. Once the current color of the drawing tool is transparent, this means there is no change. What should I do to make a non transparent pixel completely transparent?

Comment: I don't use visual studio, but in general, I would think this would affect editing of the image. If you were to blend a color with rgba(0,0,0,0), that would look different than blending the same color with rgba(255,255,255,0). It might be best to make the transparent pixels the same rgb color as the nearest opaque pixel.

Answer (score 4):

In the VS 2013 image editor, the following works for me:

1. Open a png image or other format that supports an alpha channel.
2. Select View-Toolbars-Image Editor so that you can see the toolbar
3. Select the eraser from the toolbar. Set the erase width in the propery window to 1
4. Now clicking ("erasing") a pixel will set it to transparent

Comment: I tried this with VS2012. It did not work. Can you think about other important conditions or check on VS2012? Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering specifically what happened when you erased a pixel?  Also, can you set the "animate background" option because that will make it easier to see when a pixel is being erased. Also, in the image properties what is the format of your file. Mine is 32bpp BGRA.

Answer (score 3):

> The transparency of the pixel in PNG file is determined by the value of the alpha channel

Yes, but that's actually one of the [three ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973) to get transparency on PNG.

> 0 - Transparent
>
> 255 - Opaque

(Perhaps this is obvious, but just in case) those are the extreme values, you can use any intermediate value to specify a semi-transparent pixel.

> It seems that once the pixel is set to be transparent, the RGB components of the pixel should be not important. Is that really true?

If it's fully transparent, that's basically true. If you are not interested in keeping some "original" background color, you might prefer to set the RGB components to black (all zero), because then you'd get [better compression](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/15/clever-png-optimization-techniques/).

I don't know about VS