# Batch conversion PNG w/ alpha-channel in IrfanView

Tags: png, transparency, irfanview

I have to batch convert a couple of PNG logos, each with transparent background. I used to do it with IrfanView, but now I just can't get it to work properly. I tried different options, but every one breaks transparency in some or another way.
So, if I leave all options unchecked, I basically get PNGs with background filled with color. If I check `Save Transparent Color`, IrfanView either ask me about what color to make transparent or uses `Main window color`. But why I even have to choose color? There are no 'transparent' color in my PNGs, there are just alpha-channels, which should remain alpha and not to become white or black or whatever. Sure, I can choose some harsh-pink color (which my logos do not contain) as `Main window color`, but it feels like wrong solution.

Comment: What is your conversion? Aren't you by chance saving the PNG in some other format that don't support transparency? (JPEG)

Comment: PNG to PNG. Not actually conversion, but changing sizes (because logos are quite big for web).

Comment: Are you sure you have PNG with alpha channels, aren't the indexed (palette) ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973

Comment: Same issue. PNG to PNG just resizing. Seems I cannot preserve the transparency.

Answer (score 2):

IrfanView is simply not capable of it. This is also explained in the IrfanView [forum](https://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?t=7404) (yes also after 10 years).

Comment: That's really unfortunate, seeing that this tool is very powerful for what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know since when, but IrfanView can store not only PNGs with one "transparent color" (generates a `tRNS` chunk with the one entry set to tranparent that has the same index in the `PLTE` chunk as the selected color) but also PNGs with an alpha channel (resulting in larger files without `PLTE` or `tRNS` chunks).

The latter worked for me. I needed several transparent gray values, which resulted from anti-aliasing of a b/w image.

I guess that the alpha values are not taken from the input but generated somehow, as a screenshot from a browser presenting an SVG with both transparent and white background resulted in a PNG transparent in both regions.