# Can a PNG image that is entirely opaque contain an alpha channel?

Tags: png

Is it possible to construct a png image, that is entirely opaque (that means every pixel in the image is opaque) but the image data itself has an alpha channel ?

Why is it that some PNG images don't have an alpha channel ?

Comment: To add to the accepted answer, bear in mind that the alpha channel is not the only way to have transparency in a PNG image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Just like an RGB image may contain only data in the Red channel and not in Green and Blue; "unused" channels are not a problem. Alpha is a separate channel of its own, and in particular, its values should be *independent* of the associated pixel colors: "PNG does **not** use premultiplied alpha" ([6.2 Alpha representation](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#6AlphaRepresentation)).

   Also see [12.4 Alpha channel creation](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#12Alpha-channel-creation) in the [official specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) for some additional details:

   > The alpha channel can be regarded either as a mask that temporarily hides transparent parts of the image, or as a means for constructing a non-rectangular image. In the first case, the colour values of fully transparent pixels should be preserved for future use. In the second case, the transparent pixels carry no useful data and are simply there to fill out the rectangular image area required by PNG. In this case, fully transparent pixels should all be assigned the same colour value for best compression.
2. Because they don't *need* to, per that same specification:

   > ... PNG provides a patent-free replacement for GIF and can also replace many common uses of TIFF. Indexed-color, grayscale, and truecolor images are supported, plus an **optional** alpha channel. (my emphasis)

Comment: You can think of any PNG file as representing a 16-bit-per-sample RGBA "canonical" image; if all pixels are opaque the A channel can be omitted, which implies an all-opaque A channel.  If all pixels can be represented without loss with only 1, 2, 4, or 8 bits per channel, the bit depth can be reduced.  If every pixel is some gray level with Red == Green == Blue, two of the color channels can be omitted.  In some cases the transparency/opacity can be represented more efficiently via the tRNS chunk and the A channel omitted.  This is all explained in the PNG spec.