# Android - PNG image has alpha channel, but when in imageview white background is shown. How can I fix?

Tags: android, image, imageview, png, alpha-transparency

Problem:

I have saved a png image into the @drawable folder in android studio. This image is confirmed to have an alpha channel.

Image in android studio:
[image]

When I add it to an image view in a relative layout the alpha channel is lost

ImageView image:

[image]

xml layout code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_main"
    android:id="@+id/main_icon_img"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I have tried setting the background to transparent. If I save it to a mipmap then the image will show the alpha channel, although this is not my preferred method.

Is there a reason to why its appearing with a white background?

Comment: Did you try another png transparent, and make sure you are viewing the image asset for density visualization, i guess it's a problem with the image file.

Comment: There is not problem XML..Can you pls try with some other image..

Comment: hmmm, yea you appear to be right its an a problem with the png. I created it with gimp which I have done many times before. I will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Is that really a PNG with Alpha channel? Perhaps it has a TRNS chunk instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was

`<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>`

in the theme style. This made all the views to be drawn with a white BG. Even the`TextViews`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the imageView if it has a background attribute and get rid of it as shown on this image

[image]

I also found [this site](https://www.remove.bg/) to be so helpful to enable you easily remove background from the image effectively making it PNG