# Phonegap reduce image size

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova

I have a phonegap application that has multiple input fields including textboxes/textareas/signatures/cad sketches/camera images. This data is uploaded to the server via an ajax post.

**Problem:**

When uploading the data the file is unreasonably large and takes a great deal of time to upload due to the images. When no photos are added the size is around 200kb - 400kb but with images the file has reached 60Mb and in terms of using an android device with a poor internet connection (Area with bad signal) this is unusable.

**What I have tried:**

I have used image compression in the camera options as seen in the below extract of code, however the challenge I am facing is that different devices with different camera specifications are utilized so if the device has a poor quality camera vs a device with a good quality camera image compression will take place regardless so the image quality will  be terrible.

```
 var cameraOptions = {
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    quality: 40,
                    encodingType: 0,
                };
```

Reference to the phonegap camera API and options:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

From reading the below post I deduced that jpeg is the lightest format so used the endodingType of 0

[PNG vs. GIF vs. JPEG vs. SVG - When best to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use)

**What we want to achieve:**

Limiting the image size to maximum of 500kb per image and if its larger then than that compress it.

Comment: What in the world are you doing to land JPG images that are that large? Or are you trying to upload a collection of images from a single form (even then, I would expect it to take at least 20 images to get anywhere near 60mb, and that's pushing it quite a bit).

Comment: Correct its a single dynamically built form of image fields that are used to capture photos with aproximately 15 - 25 images

Comment: Do you need the images in their original sizes? Why not limit the width/height of the captured image using targetWidth/targetHeight? It might not guarantee a 500kb image, but it would certainly help.

Comment: Having the images in the original sizes is not necessary. I was thinking of trying that and setting the width/height as a cameraOption on photo capture but I wasn't too sure what size I should use to retain a decent image.

Additional the problem is this will only work for "new" images and previously downloaded images will still retain the old size

Comment: IIRC, Facebook used to limit photos to something on the order of 1000 pixels on the long side. I think that's changed now to 2000 to better support retina displays, but if you don't need a full-screen image, you could probably get away with 500-1000px.

Comment: This plugin might be of use for resizing images after-the-fact (you could draw the image to a smaller canvas and save that data off): http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.devgeeks.canvas2imageplugin

Comment: Thanks for the advice limiting the resolution seemed to do the trick without loosing quality. Optimizations are not perfect as of yet but lost more to try and work on

Answer (score 6):

I tried with different camera options and with the following I got file sizes of 4.5MB from an iPhone 5:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    quality : 50,
    encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
});
```

Only by adding the line

```
correctOrientation : true
```

File size reduced to ~500kB.

I don't have any explanation to why it should work this way, but I suggest you try it if the quality property doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: actually it reduces over 700k using correcOrientation. +1