# Drawable image type to minimize the apk size

Tags: android, image, bitmap, apk, android-drawable

In my app there are 180 images in drawable folder & I will display them at the background of textview covering the entire screen.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) states that `Android supports bitmap files in a three formats: .png (preferred), .jpg (acceptable), .gif (discouraged).`

> It also states that Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image compression by the     aapt tool during the build process. For example, a true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors may be converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. This will result in an image of equal quality but which requires less memory. So be aware that the image binaries placed in this directory can change during the build. If you plan on reading an image as a bit stream in order to convert it to a bitmap, put your images in the res/raw/ folder instead, where they will not be optimized.

I dont want the apk size to exceed 50 MB, Can *.png images minimize the apk size as compared to other extensions(.jpg,.gif)?

Comment: In my opinion, putting images in any other format than .png is a bad idea. I would suggest that you resize your images to a size that will look good on the biggest screen and save in png format and let the optimization to be done on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already read in the documentation, the images are already compressed a great deal. However, you might want to try other compression tools available to reduce the size of images.

It's generally a better idea to save images as jpegs rather than pngs. As pngs are bigger in size because of the alpha channel (transparency). Not always though. So, in case you dont need transparency in images it'd be a better idea to switch to jpegs.

I generally use this : https://tinypng.com/

Comment: Well in my case I don't think there is a need of transparency,then why should I use jpeg ?

Comment: In that case you should convert to jpegs. It'll mostly reduce the size.

Answer (score 0):

Better you compress the .jpg files as much as possible, this should greatly reduce the size of your .apk file. And there is a  tool such as [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) and refer [APK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/) too It has great resizing options.

Comment: png & jpeg both can be compressed, with no visual change, which can be better in my case, I think png, as android prefers it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is from what i know from using photoshop,
 here is a very well explanation of why to use each: 
[PNG vs. GIF vs. JPEG vs. SVG - When best to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use) 
it can help you reduce the apk size... honestly i think it would be best for you to download photoshop (even the 30 day ver.) and simply load and save and see to comparison yourself.