# Setting the image property of a PFImageView to a local image, then updating Parse database with the PFFile

Tags: parse-platform, pffile

The `PFImageView`, with its `.file` property and its corresponding `-loadInBackground` method, is really useful. I'm having trouble figuring out how to "go the other way", i.e. get the `PFFile` reference from a new image:

RA_MyAccount.h (extract)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *profilePic;
-(IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender;
```

RA_MyAccount.m (extract)

```
-(void)setLocalImageToPFImageView:(UIImage *)localImage
{
    self.profilePic.image = localImage
}

-(IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    PFUser *cUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    // Get the PFFile reference for the new image
    PFFile *file;
    file = ??? ??? ??? ???

    // Set
    cUser[PF_USER_PIC] = file;

    [cUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:
     ^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindtotabviewsegue" sender:self];
     }];
}
```

I've indicated with `??? ??? ??? ???` where I'm having problems.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have one answer, but I'm just not convinced it's the smartest way. I'm also apprehensive to start using functions like `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` (is it even a function?) when I don't know anything about image encoding.

```
file = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilePic.image, 0.8f)];
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the you're okay with the image losing quality (should be fine if it's a photograph), then you want to do it the following way. The 0.8 represents an 80% compression quality.

```
file = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilePic.image, 0.8f)];
```

If you can't lose quality, then do it the following way.

```
file = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profilePic.image)];
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use) for a more detailed comparison of the various formats.