# Compress byte array with C# and decompress that byte Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, c#-4.0, compression

I have a server program written in c# that continuously take screen shots and send it to my android device... i want those screen shot images to compress on server side written in c# and then decompress my client side written in java... any idea please!!!!!!

Comment: You're looking for gzip.

Comment: SLaks Well, if the screenshots are in bitmap format, then general purpose compression such as gzip will certainly help. Yet, you will be better off converting them to jpeg or png or other compressed image format that will offer you a better compression ratio. Compressing a jpeg or png using gzip will return in little to no gain.

Comment: How continuously?  If you're in the 30 times a second range it's time to look at video such as mpeg.  If not then this is probably something you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-when-best-to-use