# Giving a JPEG image a .PNG ext in file name? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode

I know you can inspect an image to determine what its file format is, but just supposing you append .png to the name of an image file when it is in fact in JPEG format, are there any possible issues that can arise as a result or does it not matter to Xcode what you call it, once you have .png or .jpeg at the end of the image file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. This will cause you problems.** [They are completely different formats.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg-when-best-to-use) Although you are usually able to freely rename image extensions on your computer, [and they remain openable in image editors,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166602/why-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-file-just-by-renaming-its-extension) this is only because the editors don't necessarily rely on the extension for the format.

However, in Xcode, although it may not cause you problems initially...  somewhere down the line, it'll come back to bite you - I guarantee it.

I have no idea why you'd want to do such a thing in the first place!