# Draw single(!) pixel with php

Tags: php, gd, graphic

Can someone help me to draw **single** pixel using php GD library?
I have such code:

```
$img    = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$c      = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
$white  = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $white);
imagesetpixel($img, 0, 0, $c);
imagejpeg($img, 'created.jpg');die();
```

But the output is really weird (it is approximate image in top-left corner):

[image]

Is it possible to draw ***just one red pixel*** at x-0 y-0 position?

Comment: Use png instead of jpg, jpg uses lossy encoding, losing information in the progress

Comment: Thanks mate. It seems like it is impossible to make something with jpeg :(

Comment: You may want to read about the different image file types, and in what situations they are useful: [PNG vs. GIF vs. JPEG vs. SVG - When best to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7752936/1542723)