# Is there a way to compress gif files stored in Firebase Storage?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, gif

I'm working with an app based on Gif and after several weeks I noticed that the Gifs needed to be compressed in order for my app to run more smoothly. The problem is that I don't know how to compress the gifs that are stored on the Firebase Storage. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you mean that they take a long time to download? You can always try to size them down. Gifs aren't made for quality, they're made to have a low number of colors and pixels.

Comment: Yes, my app takes a lot of time loading the gifs in the UIImageView.

Comment: If it's user-generated pictures, I'd recommend WebP for its image size.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing a GIF that is stored in Storage consists of these steps:

1. [Read the file from storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files).
2. [Compress the GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508344/ways-to-compress-gifs-in-swift).
3. [Write the compressed data back to storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files).

Comment: And then you upload it. Don't forget that.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant local storage. Good answer!

Comment: But if my Storage contains a lot of gifs like more than a thousand, how can I make it to compress one by one?

Comment: Step 0: get a [list of the files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files), and loop over them.