# Which extension should I use for my avatar?

Tags: performance, web, html, mobile-website, avatar

I want to use 50 avatars for my website / mobile application and I wonder what extension should I use for it?

My avatars are eps now and I can export them as svg, png, etc.

Which extension is best for performance?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.png`

PNG format is a lossless compression file format, which makes it a common choice for use on the Web. PNG is a good choice for storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a small file size.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but can you explain more why?

Comment: @AminVakil.. The best way to thank someone who answers your question on this site is to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Please do so when the system allows you to. When you have enough rep, you can also vote for any answers which you find useful.

Comment: Of course PNG is a good choice for small images but in case I wanted to use this avatars in bigger sizes for any reason I could have svgs beforehand.

Comment: There is a good summary here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg-when-best-to-use