# Draw image with transparent background on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, transparent

I need to draw an image with transparent background on canvas. I have a code that should do that:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(50,50,500,500); // something in the background

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JXBD.png"; //transparent png
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

But the background is not transparent:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The actual image is not transparent.

Comment: So what background should be to add transparency effect? Can u give a link to actual transparent image then?

Comment: no specific background. PNG allows a 4th channel, the alpha channel. So every pixel has a red, green, blue and alpha value (opacity) between 0 and 255 (in case of 8bit PNG). Also see this link, for when to use which image format: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2336522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly - you just need an image with a transparent background - like this question mark:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');


ctx.fillRect(50,50,500,500); // something in the background

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPEQQ.png"; //transparent png
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

And to prove it's not just got a white background image, I set the background image of the body to `red`:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');


ctx.fillRect(50,50,500,500); // something in the background

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPEQQ.png"; //transparent png
```

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The image that you are trying to display isn't transparent, it simply just has a transparent checkered background.

A link to an image which does have a transparent background can be found [here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded)

Using this link fixes your issue:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');


ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 500, 500); // something in the background

var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"; //transparent png
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```