# Visio save as JPEG creating larger image

Tags: textbox, jpeg, visio

[image]

I have created the two images above in Visio (16.0.13426.20270) 32 bit.
The yellow rectangles in the back are 6Wx6H
I select the text box, the image, and the yellow rectangle, then save as JPEG.

The resultant image with the text at the bottom saves larger (6Wx6.266H) than the image with the text at the top (6Wx6H).

If I move the text at the bottom up further, I can save the image as 6Wx6H, so there is something causing the bottom of the text box to extend further than is visually being indicated.  I have deleted everything after HAPPY.  I copied everything from the image that works to create the image that doesn't.  I have reviewed the EFFECTS to ensure there are no shadows, etc.  Selecting everything in the text box does not reveal anything that extends beyond the visible text box selection, nor beyond the yellow rectangle, but something is.

Does anyone know why this occurring and how to stop it?

Comment: Can you attached the Visio document and we can take a look. Also, might be better to save a a PNG rather than JPG. JPEG is for photographs, not blocky graphics like this.

Comment: @PaulHerber please define better.  JPEG produces a smaller file size than PNG, so for my use-case I think JPEG is better, but curious on your perspective of better.

Comment: Here is an article explaining all better than I could do in a few lines - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/what-are-the-different-usecases-of-png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg

Answer (score 0):

My work around was to copy and paste the textbox as an image, crop it, and then save it all as a JPEG, which worked fine.

Interestingly, next day, when I reopened the original Visio, the text box selection border was much larger than originally displayed, extending beyond the yellow 6Wx6H rectangle, but I was able to select all and save as a JPEG, at identical 6Wx6H sizes.

So my conclusion is that I was encountering a bug of some kind, although I wasn't able to immediately replicate it.  Challenge for another day.