# SVG and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

Question from a beginner) Why do I get stripes between color transitions when converting an image to SVG and uploading it to android studio? How to fix it ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDj2K.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcfAS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG image format can only represent things in vectors, meaning lines or curves, as opposed to the usual pixel-based formats.

This means it is very efficient for representing diagrams, simple shapes and letters, to the point where you can [zoom endlessly into them without losing quality](https://modomodoagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/twitter-svg-png-1.png), but it cannot represent full-color realistic images with the same precision or efficiency.

Basically, you should only use SVG (and other vector-based graphics formats) for icons and simple shapes, not complex shapes with different hues of color.

Comment: For more info on file formats in general, you can also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336522/what-are-the-different-usecases-of-png-vs-gif-vs-jpeg-vs-svg